# What is the procedure for calculating the working set?

Tags: mongodb

If I have, say, a million records on Mongo DB and each record is 5 KB big.  Let us say I want to run a Map-Reduce on this data and want to estimate the RAM required for this application.  There is going to be no read or write on this DB during the map-reduce operation.  The map-reduce is going to aggregate some of the records and do logical comparisons of aggregated records.

I would like to understand how map-reduce will bring the data into RAM and hence how should the working set be calculated (Eg: should I assume that 1 MM x 5 Kb will be my working set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, the working set for a Map-Reduce job would be the entire set of data that you'll be running the map() function across. For example if your data is 1M objects and your map() function looks at every document then the working set would be 1M x 5K. If you are feeding your map() function with some subset of your data (say 500K objects) then it would be 500K x 5K. In either case, you'll have to include the sizes of any predefined indexes as well.